# Unable to execute a SSIS using a SQL Server agent job in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I've created a SSIS with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 with the user "domain\Administrator". This SSIS has two connections: one to an AS400 db and another to an SQL database. This SSIS drops a table on the SQL database and then creates a tables and fills it with the information from an AS400 db.

In Visual Studio the SSIS works great and only takes a few moments to execute.

On SQL Server 2014 I also created a job that contains just one step with the SSIS package to execute. Create a Proxy account with this user "domain\Administrator" with the credentials and all and specify in the job step that I'll be executing this step with the proxy user created.

When executing the job on SQL Server it keeps working but it doesn't stop at all. It doesn't make any change to the table of the SQL Server database.

Please, could you help me with this issue?

Comment: How is the package deployed on the SQL Server/How is agent executing the package?

Comment: What does the "All Executions" report show for the package after you run the job?

Comment: Have you seen the logs on the job monitor .Please check what errors is it posting?

Comment: I didn't deploy the project from SSIS to SQL. I created a job in SQL and execute as the proxy user as i put on the only step that i execute inside the properties of this step on "Execute as".

Comment: Sorry, since the job never ends it is not showing on the "All Executions" and also not showing any error.

Comment: Don't know where is "all executions". you should go to Sql Server Agent ->Job Activity Monitor ->Open the job->Right click view history and   and check the last successful run or the error message its shows

Comment: If you haven't deployed the package, (even via filesystem is a form of deployment, however, I recommend against that method, SSISDB is far better), how are you executing it? That doesn't make any sense. That's like saying you put the apples in the bag, but the bag is empty. Either the apples are in the bag and the bag is not empty, or the bag is empty and you didn't put the apples in there.

Comment: @rmehra76 thanks, but when I access "All executions" log I cannot find any register regarding this job since it didn't finish nor successfuly or unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Larnu. I deployed the package and execute the SSIS from there and it successfully execute but when I try to execute it inside a job it keeps on executing without ending.

Comment: *I deployed the package* and *I didn't deploy the project from SSIS* conflict. Which is it? We still need to know your deployment model as they all differ. We have very few details to work with here, and no logs. You're telling us there aren't any but that simply won't be true; there would only be no logs if the package wasn't executed, or the job was not run.